# Why does it appear I am signing into googleusercontent.com when doing gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn() from a GSuite Add On?

Tags: google-authentication, gsuite-addons

I have written a GSuite Add On that makes Google Rest API calls using https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents. To make those calls my Add On needs to be authenticated to Google using the right scopes.  So I took the usual web app code that I am used to:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
```

Before that

```
gapi.client.init()
```

is called with an API Key and Client ID. The Client ID is associated with a project in https://console.developers.google.com/ - let's call it `Mike Add On`.  I had to configure the uri that is hosting my add on as an authorised origin - it was something like

```
https://n-5eu5f2kfjyztq5mypu757655tecik5nd52mv7sztq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com
```

I would expect the project name (`Mike Add On`) to come up in the OAuth Consent screen when a user of my add on logs in.  But instead I get

```
Choose an account to continue to googleusercontent.com
```

Why is `googleusercontent.com` coming up as the app name, instead of the one associated with the Client ID?

Comment: What settings do you have in your OAuth consent screen settings in GCP?

Comment: Application Type = public, Verification status = not published, Application Name is set, Support email is set, Scope for Google APIs = [email, profile, openid], Authorized domains = [xxxx.firebaseapp.com, googleusercontent.com].  Anything else you think might be relevant @RafaGuillermo ?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using the gapi client for a G Suite Add-on? G Suite Add-ons are written in Apps Script so there is no need to use the JavaScript client. I think this may have something to do with how the name is showing as the GAS project has to be linked to the GCP project.

Comment: Rafa, I realised last week that this is correct.  I have since switched to using Advanced Services, and now there is no need for gapi.  The switch was fairly straightforward.